# Number of substrings with given constraints

Tags: string, algorithm

I am given a sorted string and I wish to count the number of substrings (not necessarily contiguous) that are possible with the following constraints:

1. All the alphabets in the substring should be in sorted order.
2. The substring must contain only 1 vowel.
3. The length of the substring should be greater than or equal to 3.

For example:

for "aabbc",
we have 3 substrings  "abc","abb","abbc" that match the above constraints.So, here 3 is the ans.

How do I go about for a general string?

I have tried this for 2-3 hours, but couldn't find a proper way. I was asked this question in a programming coding round today and I fear the same question would be asked in the interview tomorrow. Even hints or approach would be appreciated.

Comment: @tobias_k No constrains specified as such!

Comment: Is the input string always in sorted order?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Not necessarily! But you can always sort it!

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question to make it more readable!

Comment: Ah, so you don't have to select a substring, or even a subsequence, but are free to rearrange your selected characters.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and I can choose any number of characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have k vowels, and an array A specifying the histogram of each non-vowel.  (i.e. `A[0]` is the number of the first non-vowel, `A[1]` is the number of the second non-vowel.)

Then (ignoring the length constraint) we have k choices for the vowel, and `(A[0]+1)*(A[1]+1)*(A[2]+1)*...` choices for the remaining letters (for each non-vowel we can have `0,1,2,...,A[i]` choices).

This overcounts by k (for the single letter cases) and by k*len(A) for the double letter cases, so simply subtract these from the total.

Example Python code:

```
from collections import Counter
s='aabbc'

vowels = 'aeiou'
C = Counter(s)
t = 1
vowel_count = 0
cons_count = 0
for letter,count in C.items():
    if letter in vowels:
        vowel_count += 1
    else:
        cons_count += 1
        t *= count+1

print vowel_count * (t - cons_count - 1)
```